# Reserve or book tickets?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrases, verbs, expressions

In an app I am writing the user can book/reserve tickets for riding a bus.
Which of the following terms does fit this process best?
'Reserve Tickets' or 'Book Tickets'

Also, in some cases the user would need to make a change/transfer, but can buy tickets for both buses together/at the same time. How would one best describe this process?

Comment: I am not in the travel industry, but I believe that *reserving* and *booking* tickets are two different things. Which does your application do?

Comment: You pay for them right away.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically, "reserving" tickets means that you haven't paid for them yet, while "booking" tickets means that you have. A reserved ticket can be given away if you don't come in and pay for it by the deadline, but a booked ticket is guaranteed to be yours because you've already purchased it.

Comment: And as for the last part of OP's question; that would be booking or reserving a _trip_.

Comment: Whats the source for the "typically"?

Answer (score 2):

In the UK, people normally *book* tickets for different things.

Comment: But they might reserve them first.

Comment: Jon, I haven't heard of that. Perhaps the word *reserve* is more common in other parts of the world where English is spoken, outside the UK?

Comment: It's certainly used in British English, though credit card transactions over phones means there's less often any need to reserve what you can just book immediately.